# Vertically center a font using FontForge?

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I'm using [Ostrich Sans](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/ostrich-sans) as part of a project and i noticed that the font is aligned to the baseline and has a large ascender. I tried but cannot vertically align this through CSS.

How can I modify the font pack itself in a tool such as FontForge such that the font is vertically centered?

[image]

Comment: Font editing software allow radical edits, this shouldn't be an exception. Another thing is as important: Does the author of the font allow customized versions? If this is a free font, also free to modify and distribute, one thing is quite sure: You have no right to use text "Ostrich Sans" in the name of the modified version. Read the license. It's your job to find it.

Comment: @user287001 - fair enough, I deleted it. No insult to anyone was intended. It was just the play on words that struck me as apt,  "Ostrich sans" and the word "sands".

Comment: For me the ostrich in sand comment was humour, but the moderator decides and he has four times decided differently than me.

Comment: @user287001 - absolutely. Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

I had spent all morning looking for a tutorial for this. [Here is a YT video that might help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiylAy15ORI). I've figured that it's the ratio between the ascent and descent values that matters. In my case, the descent was 800 while the ascent was 2533 which was causing my font to be shifted more towards the top. When I reduced the descent to 600 and increased the ascent to 2733 (keeping the total same) with the instruction shared in the video, the font became much more centered visually. Hope this helps someone!